# How to unhook a function in Woocommerce Template?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I have a basic question that has always stumped me. I'm trying to move the Star Rating into the comment meta, which will help me style it. Here's the template file `review.php` section:

```
<div class="comment-text">

           <?php
           /**
            * The woocommerce_review_before_comment_meta hook.
            *
            * @hooked woocommerce_review_display_rating - 10 //Want to unhook this.
            */
           do_action('woocommerce_review_before_comment_meta', $comment);

           /**
            * The woocommerce_review_meta hook.
            *
            * @hooked woocommerce_review_display_meta - 10
            */
           do_action('woocommerce_review_meta', $comment);

           do_action('woocommerce_review_before_comment_text', $comment);

           /**
            * The woocommerce_review_comment_text hook
            *
            * @hooked woocommerce_review_display_comment_text - 10
            */
           do_action('woocommerce_review_comment_text', $comment);

           do_action('woocommerce_review_after_comment_text', $comment);
           ?>

       </div>
```

I was thinking I could add the following to my functions.php:

```
    remove_action('woocommerce_review_display_rating', 10);
```

And add it back in the review-meta.php, but I can't remove / unhook the star rating. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `10` is not the name of a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unhook the function from that action specifically:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_before_comment_meta',
               'woocommerce_review_display_rating', 10 );
```

(e.g. look for the opposite add_action() line in includes/wc-template-hooks.php)

You'll also need to make sure that this is run after WooCommerce has loaded and added the action you're about to remove, e.g. place this in a plugins_loaded hook:

```php
function unhook_display_rating() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_review_before_comment_meta',
                   'woocommerce_review_display_rating', 10 );
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'unhook_display_rating', 10, 0 );
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I appreciate the help.

Comment: How would I then add the rating back into review-meta.php? Would I `do_action('woocommerce_review_display_rating');` in the template file?

Comment: No, you can't call it with an action anymore. You could just call the function: `woocommerce_review_display_rating();`

Answer (score 3):

`remove_action` requires that the second parameter is the name of the function/callable that was added, and the priority must match what was added.

[The official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/) says its parameters are:

```php
remove_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_remove, int $priority = 10 )
```

You can use also `remove_all_actions`:

```php
remove_all_actions( 'hook name' );
```

Remember, hooks are like events, you can't remove something that hasn't been added yet, so *when* you call this function matters, not just how it's called.